# Building hello world with nana

Tags: c++, cmake, nana

Im trying to build my first project with the nana gui lib. I never really worked with other libraries and thus have no experience with cmake.

I installed the library using `cmake, make, make install` and got through with not error.

When trying to compile the [starter project](http://nanapro.org/en-us/blog/2016/05/an-introduction-to-nana-c-library/) I get some errors

> [ 50%] Building CXX object CmakeFiles /NanaProTest.dir/main.cpp.o
>
> [100%] Linking CXX executable NanaProTest CmakeFiles
>
> /NanaProTest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function 'main':
>
> /home/xxx/CLionProjects/NanaProTest/main.cpp:6 undefined reference to 'nana::appearance::appearance()' /home/
>
> local/include/nana/gui/widgets/form.hpp:63 undefined reference to 'nana::API::make_center(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
>
> ...

My current CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(NanaProTest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories(/home/xxx/libs/nana/source)
add_executable(NanaProTest main.cpp)
```

Im pretty sure I need to add something to my CMakeLists.txt but I cant figure out what.

Comment: You're missing `target_link_libraries`. Including headers is not enough.

Comment: @Evg That was the answer, thank you very much!